# Remove Price Pfister shower cartridge

Tags: shower, cartridge, mixing-valve

I'm trying to replace a Price Pfister single handle (avante?) shower valve.

I've unscrewed the chrome nut that is on the outside, leaving what I believe to be a washer surrounding the valve stem.  But just pulling forward on the valve (even with the handle fixed on) doesn't seem to budge or show any movement.

I've tried prying behind what I think is the washer on the outside, but because of the setback, I can't get anything behind it.

[image: shower mixing valve]

Do I just need to pry that washer out of there with something, or is there anything more to do before the cartridge will release?

Answer (score 3):

Your cartridge looks similar to the one in the photo below from home Depot. It extends close to 3 1/2" into the valve base and has two tight fitting "o" rings that have stuck to the sides. Try pouring some CLR or vinegar into the cartridge area to disolve the lime and Calcium buildup. Replace the handle screw and gently pry it outward against a block over the brass opening to break the cartridge loose from the valve base.

[image]

Comment: Will use some vinegar when I pull everything apart again for another try next weekend.

Answer (score 1):

When I removed mine it was really stuck in there as well. I replaced the screw and grabbed onto the screw with pliers, pushed in on it and yanked out really hard and it finally came loose after a couple of tries.

When I replaced a different one I did not get so lucky and it actually broke apart on me and I had to remove it piece by piece being really careful not to damage the brass.